# How do I fix the error " Message: Error: Polling for changes failed: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource" in firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, firefoxdriver

I'm always getting the below error when I run my automation suite. I need to fix that error because it fails some of my tests when the browser is loading.

> console.error: BroadcastService: 
>     receivedBroadcastMessage: handler for
>     remote-settings/monitor_changes
>     threw error:
>     Message: Error: Polling for changes failed: NetworkError when 
>     attempting to fetch resource..
>     Stack:
>
> remoteSettingsFunction/remoteSettings.pollChanges@resource://services-settings/remote-settings.js:188:13

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that is throwing the error.

Comment: hi , this error is throwing sporadically. so there is no specific code . if this error occured once in one place it's not occuring again at the same place.

Comment: Do you have your firefox driver version up to date with your browser version?

Comment: yes . i'm using latest firefox version 65.0.1. i'm not sure whether it's a firefox bug . but how ever my automation scripts are failing sporadically